# IllegalArgumentException while trying to invoke method

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

My code is like the following :

```
Class<?> targetClass = Class.forName(class_name);
mthd = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod(function_name, new Class[]{Object.class});
mthd.invoke(new Object());  //fails
```

why when ever i try to invoke my method `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
...
```

what I am missing?

UPDATE:
the called function is :

```
public static String categoryCount(Object val){
        System.out.println(val.toString());
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the method signature you try to invoke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mthd.invoke` needs two arguments in your case.
First is the object to run the invoked method, second is an argument for `categoryCount(val)`.

In case of a static method (like you have) use:

```
mthd.invoke(null, new Object());
```

For non-static method, use:

```
mthd.invoke(myObj, new Object());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(class_name);
Method method = clazz.getMethod("categoryCount", Object.class);
Object o = method.invoke(null, new Object());
```

Works fine

Comment: Works fine only if `categoryCount` is a static method.

Comment: According to the question it is.